# How can i create multiple authendication in laravel api?

Tags: laravel, api

I have two different registers and logins. How can i create multiple authendication for that using laravel api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little bit tricky because [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport) doesn't currently support multiple authentication yet. What I did with a previous project of mine is use [this](https://github.com/sfelix-martins/passport-multiauth) package for implementing multiple authentication for APIs using Laravel Passport. The package I've suggested is fairly simple to implement. Go check it out!

Comment: Thanks man @rkg It is working for me and i am stuck in logout also can you help me out